# From tex to docx using pandoc. Bibliography issue

Tags: pandoc

I am trying to convert a tex file to docx using pandoc. The tex file contains a bibliography, which is in an external file, named mybib.bib, but located in the same folder of the main document. The package pandoc-citeproc has been installed with pandoc. I type in the cmd terminal:

```
pandoc -s main.tex bibliography=mybib.bib -o main.docx
```

However, the bibliography is not converted in the docx file. Do you have an idea why this happens?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to tell `pandoc` to use `pandoc-citeproc`. For recent versions (>= 2.11) of `pandoc`  you need to use the option `--citeproc`:

```
pandoc -s main.tex --citeproc --bibliography=mybib.bib -o main.docx
```

Elder versions use `pandoc-citeproc` as a filter:

```
pandoc -s main.tex --filter=pandoc-citeproc --bibliography=mybib.bib -o main.docx
```

This is documented in pandoc's [manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#citation)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried as you suggested and I got: pandoc.exe: bibliography=mybib.bib: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory). But the file mybib.bib is in that directory. Am I missing something elese?

Comment: Just seeing it now, you've got the option wrong: It must be `--bibliography=mybib.bib` not `bibliography=mybib.bib`

Comment: Thank you very much, It worked. Just out of curiosity. I tried to make the conversion from a folder that is located in Onedrive and the procedure gave me a blanck document. I had to move the file into another folder (out of a cloud) and it worked (thanks to your suggestions obviously). Do you have an idea about the reason of that? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with OneDrive at all