# Convert latex to word with pandoc but no citations

Tags: pandoc, conversion

I am trying to convert a document from .tex to word using the command

```
pandoc -s main.tex --bibliography=library.bib -o testdoc.docx
```

However, there are no citations either in the text or at the end of the file.

The main.tex file compiles without any issues. I do have pandoc citeproc installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From tex to docx using pandoc. Bibliography issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569040/from-tex-to-docx-using-pandoc-bibliography-issue)

Comment: Following https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569040/from-tex-to-docx-using-pandoc-bibliography-issue?rq=1 and others, you have to call citeproc explicitely by using `--citeproc`.